# How to derive first return points from a raw LAS data file

Tags: arcgis-pro, dem, lidar, las

[image]I have a raw (never classified) las dataset derived from UAV that I am attempting to obtain a DEM, DSM, and eventually CHM from. I have successfully been able to classify ground points and vegetation within ArcGIS Pro, but am not sure how to go about getting first return points. Only last return points are available. I can use the ground classified points to get the DEM but I need the first return for the DSM.

I have never worked with LiDAR data before so this is new to me. Does anyone have any suggestions or been able to figure this out?

Comment: Is it a LiDAR sensor or photographic autocorelation derived LAS? Does your sensor support multiple returns? Are you trying to create a LAS/LAZ file with only first return points or filter the LAS Dataset? The filter, and statistics, are a property of a LAS dataset layer, there should be options for single, first of many etc in the layer properties, check the statistics to be sure that you have first/last points. Have a read of https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/las-dataset/change-filters-for-a-las-dataset.htm

Comment: It has to be photographic autocorrelation derived as its coming from an RGB drone and not a Lidar sensor. I only want the first returns to create a DSM. I added a picture of what las filter options I have to the main post. It only gives me last returns.

Comment: photogrammetric point clouds do not have multiple returns. All of your points are derived from tie points between overlapping images and not from laser pulses, so the return number is meaningless metadata in this context.

Comment: So there's no possibility of creating a DSM from the las file then?

Comment: A DSM is a maximum absolute elevation raster using all (non-noise) points, first return means nothing in that context. Do you have a 3d analyst extension? If so the tool you want is LAS Dataset to Raster https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/conversion/las-dataset-to-raster.htm with the *cell assignment method* of MAXIMUM. Creating a (bare earth) DEM on the other hand could be tricky, especially if you have lots of vegetation: photo sensors have no penetration, therefore detecting the ground is virtually impossible unless you're surveying a salt pan or open cut mine.